# AWS Cognito Authorize API call Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a API which Authenticate by AWS cognito service. i wanted to call it using ajax .i used below code for that.

```
  $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://XXXXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXX/setusername',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {},
                    header :{'Authorization':result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()},
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('Error in Operation');
                    }
                });
```

but it gives me below error when i execute it.(Note: when i remove cognito Auth from API gateway this working fine)

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enTrw.jpg)

[and below is my integration response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb1Pr.jpg)

Comment: Shouldn't this be done server side?

Comment: The way i setup my application it has to send through ajax

Comment: Well I understand that's how you need it, and perhaps it's my lack of knowledge so forgive me, but in the .NET world, we have to do OAuth stuff on server side.

Comment: Can you update your question with details about the response you get in your browser? I am not sure about your setup, but maybe you forgot to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in the Lambda function itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this library to sign the call to your API Lambda method `https://github.com/mhart/aws4`

or are you using a custom auth?